# LUIS Utterance and response tracking

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

What is the best way to track what requests were made to `LUIS` and `QnA Maker` and what the response's were?

I don't want to log the utterances and responses in any DB, I need something like `AppInsights`.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible to do this, and there are a lot of built-in pieces to do so. You don't mention what language/environment you're using (.net or node), but here are some starting points to look at:

1. [Add telemetry to your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#enabling-telemetry-to-capture-usage-data-from-other-services-like-luis-and-qna-maker) (this link will take you straight to the section on LUIS & QnA Maker)
2. [Add telemetry to your QnAMaker bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry-qnamaker?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#the-application-insights-dashboard)

The equivalent is possible in node, I'd imagine, if that's your language of choice. If so, [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-language-understanding/tree/master/documentation-samples/tutorial-web-app-bot-application-insights/v4/luis-nodejs-bot-johnsmith-src-telemetry) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

For **Qna Maker**, as long as you enabled Application Insights when you created your QnA Maker service, all you need to do is create and run the queries in Logs. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/get-analytics-knowledge-base) gives many examples of analytics you can run.

For **LUIS**, the link Hilton provided works for C#, but for node you need a different approach. [This example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-nodejs-tutorial-bf-v4) will show you how to create a LUIS App Insights helper in node and send the traces to Application insights. It doesn't give you an example queries, but here are a few I use and have found useful. If there's some specific metric you're looking for, let me know.

---

Pie chart of intents over the last 30 days

```sql
requests
| where url endswith "messages"
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| project timestamp, duration, performanceBucket, resultCode, url, id
| parse kind = regex url with *"(?i)http://"botName".azurewebsites.net/api/messages"
| join kind= inner (
traces | extend id = operation_ParentId
) on id
| where message == "LUIS"
| extend topIntent = tostring(customDimensions.LUIS_luisResponse_luisResult_topScoringIntent_intent)
| where topIntent != "None"
| where topIntent != ""
| summarize count() by topIntent
| order by count_ desc
| render piechart
```

---

List of queries with results below 0.5 confidence score

```sql
requests
| where url endswith "messages"
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| project timestamp, duration, performanceBucket, resultCode, url, id
| parse kind = regex url with *"(?i)http://"botName".azurewebsites.net/api/messages"
| join kind= inner (
traces | extend id = operation_ParentId
) on id
| where message == "LUIS"
| extend topIntent = tostring(customDimensions.LUIS_luisResponse_luisResult_topScoringIntent_intent)
| extend score = todouble(customDimensions.LUIS_luisResponse_luisResult_topScoringIntent_score)
| extend utterance = tostring(customDimensions.LUIS_luisResponse_text)
| order by timestamp desc nulls last
| project timestamp, botName, topIntent, score, utterance, performanceBucket, duration, resultCode
| where score < 0.5
```

---

Average number of messages per conversation

```sql
requests
| where url endswith "messages"
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| project timestamp, url, id
| parse kind = regex url with *"(?i)http://"botName".azurewebsites.net/api/messages"
| join kind= inner (
traces | extend id = operation_ParentId
) on id
| where message == "LUIS"
| extend convID = tostring(customDimensions.LUIS_botContext_conversation_id)
| order by timestamp desc nulls last
| project timestamp, botName, convID
| summarize messages=count() by conversation=convID
| summarize conversations=count(), messageAverage=avg(messages)
```